# Special characters 'ű' and 'ő' display problems with embedded font family

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am currently building a multi lingual web site and using a custom font called 'Exo'. This font family contains special characters 'ű' and 'ő' from the Hungarian alphabet. I embedded the 'Exo' font to the website but unfortunately these characters don't display properly. The rest of the text is displayed with the embedded 'Exo' font but these characters are displayed with the default font family.

Here is the character encoding what I use:

`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="hu">
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8>`

What could possibly be the problem?

These characters display properly on http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/exo?q%5Bterm%5D=exo&q%5Bsearch_check%5D=Y where I have downloaded the font family from.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your font is loaded correctly since you see all Latin glyps. But the font you use does not contain the Hungarian subset. That means these special Hungarian glyphs just don't exist in the font. What happens is that the css font stack will display the fallback font for the missing glyphs.

**Sort answer: What you need to do is make sure you use a version of the Exo font that contains all the subsets you need.**

You can download a new (full glyph set) OTF from FontSquirrel and use the Webfont generator to create new webfonts like you did before. But now make sure you get the subset settings right...
[image]

FontSquirrel has a fine grained subset control. This means you only need to include the language support (subsets) you need. This way loading time will stay at a minimum.

Google commissioned the design and redesign of the Exo font family. The also have a excellent delivery network. So you might consider getting your font directly from the source:  http://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Exo+2

Again, you need to load the 'Latin Extended (latin-ext)' to get all needed glyphs. The gauge shows that loading this set of glyphs triples loading time.

Although there are other ways to specify a more restrictive subset, I would go for the Latin Extended because than you keep the advantage of the CDN. Exo might already be in your users browser cache.

Comment: it is very bad practice to convert TTF to webfonts. it could cause crappy glyphs.

Comment: Thanks, that should be OTF. Why would TTF be crappy? Can you explain?

Comment: because TTF is only for windows and there is no perfect converting of fonts. some vectors could be damaged and especially with small font-size.

Comment: True Type is developed by Apple and adopted by Windows. https://developer.apple.com/fonts/TrueType-Reference-Manual/ there is only one outline per glyph used at all font sizes. So the vector shape is not damaged. Yes fonts are complex pieces of software and writing good hinting instructions is something for experts.

Comment: yep, so you need to include all font formats like svg, eot, ttf, woff, woff2 to make sure, that your font will be displayed as good, as possible. And try not to use converters. I remember, when I was trying to convert Helvetica Neue to formats other from Mac OS X system font format... convertation works, but font become so crappy :(

Comment: Thats not the point of my answer. I'll edit it. Maybe you will understand.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I downloaded the correct subsets as suggested and it sorted out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've used Google Fonts service and all seems to be okay.

https://jsfiddle.net/maxim_mazurok/wp1powya/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="hu">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
    <body style="font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif; font-size:60px">
     'ű' and 'ő' 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ik doesn't answer the question... It's not 'What works?' But 'what could possibly be the problem?' ;)

Comment: @allcaps actually, it depends. I do not even see the code of how the font is implemented to the web-page. also it depends of OS, browser, and personal settings.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is a very nice workaround to display the missing characters on the website with Exo font family, works perfectly well. However this solution did not give me explanation to the original question.

Comment: This is off course nice for Google to get all these hits and measure your site popularity. I suspect this is the only reason why they are hosting Fonts in the first place.